# List of Items we cannot migrate with Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, migration, data-migration

I have to migrate whole Full Copy Sandbox org to my new Production that includes the following  majorly:

1. All Standard/Custom object records.
2. All Note & Attachments part.
3. All Libraries & Content within them.
4. Chatter Feeds for few selected objects. etc.

But as per my knowledge there are few things which we cannot migrate through API (Apex Data Loader) eg.

a. We cannot create Libraries from DL nor we load contents within Libraries with it.
b. We cannot migrate all the type of Chatter Feeds with DL.

I believe there are some more items also which cannot be migrated with DataLoader(DL) and there only way to migrate them manually ! Can anyone list those out other then the 2 I mentioned.

Thanks !
Chirag

Comment: any other suggestions by anyone. Thanks in Advance !

Comment: It needs to be said that using a sandbox for production data is against the terms of use of Salesforce, so you should not have any expectations of migrating Chatter or any history records.

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries exist you can upload Content through dataloader and a local hard drive. I'm doing this myself currently for a migration of 12000 records so it can be done.

More info @ https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_content.htm&language=en_US

Edited:
I was incorrect about the ContentURL field it's for uploading links to websites:
Description
URL for links. This is only set for links. One of the fields that determines the FileType
From: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

Comment: Thanks #Girbot, How can we load Public Contents via URL, can you please describe it's process in more detail !

Comment: Apologies I was incorrect about the ContentUrl field: Description
URL for links. This is only set for links. One of the fields that determines the FileType. from: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge the history of the object we will not be able to migrate because history automatically create when any changes made by user on record and also  they don’t have creatable and updatable attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This popped in my news feed and I thought to add my update to it based on recent salesforce features.

1. Custom  Metadata being a metadata record cannot be migrated via Data Loader ( But its fine as they can be deployed)
2. Platform Events the next big things cant be migrated.

Comment: N.B. Platform Events are transient - they have to be consumed or they age out. They can't be queried. Hard to see why one would expect to migrate these from sandbox to prod